# JStree - build reverse tree

Tags: jquery, jstree

Is it possible to build the tree reversed using JStree? In other words, I want every node to be added on top of the previous node. This is the desired output:

```
Node 3
   - Node 2
      - Node 1
```

Comment: What does your data source look like? With JSON data you can specify what the parent node or child node of a given node will be.

Comment: This is the data source: `[{"id":1,"parent":"#","text":"Indicator","param":"non-deletable","type":"root","children":false,"selected"
:true,"opened":true},{"id":4,"parent":1,"text":"Goal","param":"","type":"default","children":false,"selected"
:true,"opened":true},{"id":5,"parent":4,"text":"Target","param":"","type":"default","children":false
,"selected":true,"opened":true}]`
I'm not sure how can I manage to change the direction of newly added nodes

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, so you actually want the tree to work such that parents are on the bottom and they expand up so that their children appear above them. I was hoping you could kind of hack your data to display it backwards but having two children to one parent this way won't be as easy